# How to change one attribute in xml so that it affects all different screen size layouts of the same?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a screen that has different layouts for different screen sizes in android. And I want to change just one attribute of the widget in normal screen size so it does not affect all other layouts. I am doing it manually. I want it to change automatically if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like this where we have similar attributes of a Widget and using it at more than 1 place, the best approach is to define a style and then use it in your all files. In that way, you can update any attribute just once in your styles file and it will be update at all its usages.

For example, take a look at this Progress bar style which is defined in styles.xml.

```
   <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar</item>
    </style>
```

Then in your layout file, just do this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/data_progress_bar"
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"/>
```